# SageMaker Neo compilation for PyTorch BERT

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, bert-language-model, amazon-sagemaker-compilers, amazon-sagemaker-neo

I'm trying to optimize a BERT model with SageMaker Neo that is pre-trained using PyTorch, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ClientError: InputConfiguration: Exactly one .pt or .pth file is allowed for PyTorch models.
```

My model.tar.gz is only having the model.pth file in the root.

What am I missing here?